# How to print all environment variables?

Tags: printing, variable

Many languages have a `printenv` or `list` or `str()` command that allows you to see the run-time environment of the variables assigned... By "environment variables" I mean to include values as they are being specified.  Is there a sort of trace feature if the value is changing over time?

I can use `typeout` to print "known variables and their values" such as:

```
\typeout{The footnote: \thefootnote}
\typeout{The footnote (arabic): \arabic{\thefootnote}}
\typeout{The footnote (value): \value{\thefootnote}}
```

What if I want to know the variables and their values abstractly, without expressing each.

Comment: `\arabic{\thefootnote}` and `\value{\thefootnote}` are wrong, use `\arabic{footnote}` and `\value{footnote}` instead. More importantly, what is the purpose of this? You have one counter, `footnote`, and tons of representations thereof, which everyone can extend. (I once played with Egyptian numerals.) What do you expect to get from this?

Comment: I am just trying to understand the differrent representations of \thefootnote

Comment: The primary question is to assess the ```\value{}``` of all variables in the document, without having to manually specify them.  The \footnote seemed to be the easiest example of a single variable with a known name.... How to list all variables, such that one is \thefootnote?

Comment: I still do not understand the question. A counter, well, counts. So you can represent the number "three" as 3, iii, c, `\gamma` or whatever, this does not add any information. These are just representations of the same number. Arguably there are arbitrarily many of them. The question which counters are used in a document, and which values they assume at a given point, is IMHO much more meaningful.

Comment: your question is very hard to understand as tex doesn't really have variables and the code fragments that you show are syntax errors that make no output.

Answer (score 2):

LaTeX maintains a list of all counters that are declared by `\newcounter` (I am assuming that this is what you mean by "variable") so you can execute the list to print the values.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\section{aaa}
\subsection{bbb}
x

\makeatletter
\def\@elt#1{\typeout{counter: #1, value: \the\value{#1}, representation: \csname the#1\endcsname}}
\cl@@ckpt

\end{document}
```

produces

```
counter: page, value: 1, representation: 1
counter: equation, value: 0, representation: 0
counter: enumi, value: 0, representation: 0
counter: enumii, value: 0, representation: 
counter: enumiii, value: 0, representation: 
counter: enumiv, value: 0, representation: 
counter: footnote, value: 0, representation: 0
counter: mpfootnote, value: 0, representation: {\itshape }
counter: part, value: 0, representation: 
counter: section, value: 1, representation: 1
counter: subsection, value: 1, representation: 1.1
counter: subsubsection, value: 0, representation: 1.1.0
counter: paragraph, value: 0, representation: 1.1.0.0
counter: subparagraph, value: 0, representation: 1.1.0.0.0
counter: figure, value: 0, representation: 0
counter: table, value: 0, representation: 0
```

Comment: You could add `\stepcounter{#1}`, then there would be no empty representations.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer yes but all the values would be one out:-)

Comment: You could set all to  11 (42 wouldn't work with the alph ;-().

Comment: @UlrikeFischer but joking aside I think the intention of the question is to print the _current_ values of all counters.